# Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded (Laravel 5.7.29)

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to insert a string in the MySQL database.
When in a string there is '%' and 'f' both come without space like (mass (%fat free mass)) then Laravel returns the following error:

exception: "InvalidArgumentException"
file: "\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse.php"
line: 75
message: "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded"

and in log file, Laravel writes this error:  1366 Incorrect string value: '\xFAt fre...' for column

I am using MariaDB  10.4.14 with engine InnoDB and character set utf8mb4 and collation utf8mb4_unicode_ci
Laravel version is 5.7.29.

Here is my query
`\DB::table('myTable')->insertGetId(['content' => utf8_encode($content), 'DDate' => NOW(), 'query_words' => 50, 'user_id' => 1]);`

Note:
It's working when I set strict mode to false. But I want this to work when strict mode is true.

Any help highly appreciated